# how to store value of attribute (href) in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**How to store value of attribute 'href' of links in a variable**

Here's the link i had tried it, but not working:

```js
var xyz = $('a.tesla').attr('href','');
alert(xyz);
```

```html
<ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
  <!--<li><a href="logo.html">Logo</a></li>-->
  <li><a href="color.html">Color</a></li>
  <li><a href="iconography.html">Iconography</a></li>
  <!--<li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>-->
  <li><a href="grid-system.html">Grid</a></li>
  <!--<li><a href="#">Layer</a></li>-->
</ul>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ty846Lyy/1/)**

Comment: Are you trying to set or get the 'href'? `elem.getAttribute('href')` would get the attribute from the element.

Comment: $('a.tesla').attr('href','') return jQuery object, just use `$('a.tesla').attr('href')`

Comment: To **get** the `href`, don't provide the second argument: `var xyz = $('a.tesla').attr('href'/*no second argument here*/);` What you're doing is *setting* the href to a blank string (and then getting a reference to the jQuery set containing elements matching `a.tesla`). [Documentation is your friend](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). :-)

Comment: Well, by using `var xyz = $('a.tesla').attr('href','');` you are actually setting the href attribute to an emoty string!!! If you want to `get` the href, then lose the second argument:  `var xyz = $('a.tesla').attr('href');`

Comment: `var h = $("a").attr("href")`  anything else is just getting your selector right (eg where's your `anchor` with class "tesla"?)

Comment: Here is the updated link https://jsfiddle.net/ty846Lyy/15/

Comment: There is no anchor with the class `tesla` ...?!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but here's your code fixed:

https://jsfiddle.net/ty846Lyy/11/

You were setting the `HREF` attribute to '', and there was no `a` element (link) with a `.tesla` class.

To get the href attribute from any link, just do:

```
var xyz = $(selector).attr('href');
```

where `selector` is any valid jQuery selector returning one or more link elements.

Comment: It is still the same for me, and what's happening is this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113879/how-to-store-value-of-attribute-href-in-a-variable/49114027?noredirect=1#comment85232788_49113879